# IPv6 packets to docker container appear to come from IPv4 of docker network gateway

Tags: docker, ipv6, ipv4

I have a HTTP server running in a Docker container. I need to be able to log requests in this container, including their source IPs, but all packets over IPv6 appear to come from the IPv4 address of the Docker network's gateway.

This originally made sense, as the Docker network did not have IPv6 enabled, so I assume Docker automatically translated to IPv4, but having enabled IPv6 on the network, I see no change. This likely means that I configured something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My network configuration is as follows (created by Portainer):

```
    {
        "Name": "aais",
        "Id": "2823152591e7f437244623ba46f66aff7eacba2e92942fbcf681f2f145fff783",
        "Created": "2021-01-11T21:52:27.632515156Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "Subnet": "fd00:1255:2111::/48",
                    "Gateway": "fd00:1255:2111::1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "6931497b76e36992c1ec9d2c6fadf4ed8492f8d7dd1bb4b01b2796f0e5204969": {
                "Name": "caddy",
                "EndpointID": "be6bb2824a3f7c5ddb73ec45c5b37d7c439a461a65d00759e7eab68edb49548c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": "fd00:1255:2111::2/48"
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "false",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a semi-temporary solution, namely:

https://github.com/robbertkl/docker-ipv6nat

which makes configuring IPv6 in docker much simpler. However, a similar feature is expected to come do Docker soon anyway, as tracked by:

- https://github.com/robbertkl/docker-ipv6nat/issues/65
- https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/pull/2572

So this should be the preferred solution for any future users.